# NSUserDefaults How Can I Check If It Gets Saved If User Deletes App Out Of Memory?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

Guys I have a quick question. I read a few similar answers, but they were less pragmatic.

When you quit xCode the `NSUserDefaults` don't get saved. But how can I *check* when I put my application out the memory of an iPhone (on a real device) that my `NSUserDefaults` do get saved? Is that possible to check on simulator? Or is my code wrong?

I have this code in a view controller that I call `settingsViewController` (there is no `NSUserDefaults` in my `appDelegate`).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
}

- (IBAction)firstAlert:(UISwitch *)sender
{
    [defaults setBool:firstAlert.on forKey:@"firstAlert"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    NSLog(@"%d",[defaults boolForKey:@"firstAlert"]);
}
```

Comment: Sending a synchronize message makes the defaults save immediately. When the app gets (force-) terminated there's nothing to synchronize any more. So what's your problem?

Comment: So that means I have to save it to disk via NSCoding if I want the settings to survive an app termination?

Comment: How's `NSCoding` involved? I though you were just saving a bool to `NSUserDefaults`?

Comment: Yea I am, and my goal is it to have a persistent state of the settings and I have the idea NSUserDefaults isn't persistent (with app termination) and there is no way to check that. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000318-CIHDDEGI) of `synchronize`.

Comment: Yea it says it does, but I have no way to check if it's stored, where it is stored and what the values in this store are. That's my question. Because when I restart my app, they won't get saved.

Comment: It will store to NSUserDefaults when you call `synchronise`. The docs recommend against calling this every time as it's automatically called eventually, but if you don't there's no guarantee it'll save if the app exits/crashes before iOS calls it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual backing store for (the local domain of) `NSUserDefaults` is in `Library/Preferences/<bundle-identifier>.plist`. You can copy this file to your Mac and inspect its contents with Xcode.

If you find that your preferences do not get saved I'd have a look into your `defaults` variable. I bet it's not initialized.

Comment: Thanks this helped. My file location is a bit different, but thanks to following Core Data tutorials from Stanford CS193P and debugging the url values and this answer I was able to find the file, it's in file://localhost/Users/username/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.1/Applications/take_most_recently_used_gibberish_string/Library/Preferences/

Answer (score 1):

When you quit xcode by hitting stop it wont save. Hit home button and try it .

```
NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
if (standardUserDefaults) { 
    [standardUserDefaults setObject:myString forKey:@"Prefs"]; 
    [standardUserDefaults synchronize]; 
}
```

Comment: Sail if you highlight your code and hit `Ctrl+k`, it'll format it as code for you (you can see below it)

Comment: I answered this from my mobile.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answer of Nikolai Ruhe I understood what I missed and why I asked the question in the first place. It seemed that the initial settings weren't set and that's because I did not pass these lines of code into my `viewDidLoad`. It's the same answer as Sail, but I didn't see the connection between that code and `viewDidLoad` yet. This is the complete implementation needed in my method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if(defaults){
        firstAlert.on = [defaults boolForKey:@"firstAlert"];
    }
}
```

Note that this isn't the answer to my real question, the real answer was Nikolai's one. This answer just shows how I used his answer to understand the root of my problem.